# Problem creating a frequency array of a given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, fortran

I am trying to create a frequency array of a given array on Fortran 95. For instance if I have an array (\1 2 4 2 4 2 5), the frequency array should be the number of times each item appears; (\1 3 2 3 2 3 1). So because there are only 1 of 5s in the original array, the last entry in the new array is 1 and because there are 3 of 2s in the original array, the corresponding entries on the new array is a 2.

Below is a sample of the code I have, but I keep getting errors. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to give me some guidance and help on what I could be doing wrong. It would be very much appreciated.

I haven't included the part of the code that generates my original array because I'm pretty sure it is correct so here is just the subroutine for the frequency array. Also the original array was sorted in ascending order outside this subroutine. Perhaps I didn't pass the original array, num(i) correctly??

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(100)::num(100)
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(100)::freq(100)
    INTEGER:: i=0, k=0, numinteger, count=0

CALL FreqArray(num, numinteger,freq)


SUBROUTINE FreqArray(num, numinteger, freq)

INTEGER, INTENT(IN):: num(100), numinteger
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT):: freq(100)

DO i=1,9
    count=0
    DO k=1, numinteger
        IF (num(k)==i)THEN
            count=count+1
        END IF
    END DO
    freq(i)=count
END DO

PRINT*, "Frequency of Digits"
PRINT*, " "
WRITE(*,'(1X,A,T35,A)'),"Digit","Frequency"
WRITE(*,'(1X,I1,T35,I1)'),num(i),freq(i)


END SUBROUTINE
```

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: "but I keep getting errors" - it would help others to help you if you were more specific.

Comment: @aix The error I get is this: "Error: Array argument at [CALL FreqArray(num, numinteger,freq)
] is smaller than the dummy size." Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you replace the `9` in `freq(9)` with `100`?

Comment: It compiles, but the num(i) and the freq(i) array both don't print as intended. The 'frequency' column has a star underneath it while the 'Digits' column has a '9' underneath.

Comment: I can't figure out if it is the formatting that is erroneous or something else.

Comment: I know next to no Fortran, but the fact that you're using `i` to index things in `write` looks suspicious.

Comment: The algorithm that is implemented in your code does not match the description you give of it. According to your description, you should assign as many elements of `freq` as there are in `num`, but your code assigns exactly 9 elements of `freq`, regardless of the value of `numinteger`, which appears to represent the number of elements of `num` that contain a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your display issue, I suspect that you meant to have a loop around

```
WRITE(*,'(1X,I1,T35,I1)'),num(i),freq(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the "(9)" is overriding the "DIMENSION(100)" making "freq" an array of length 9.  Thus for the third argument the actual argument is length 9, while the dummy is length 100.   Which causes your error message "actual argument ... is smaller than dummy size".

Other suggestions: you could make the subroutine more general using declarations "..., dimension (:) ::  num".    Then use the "size" intrinsic to determine the size of the num.   freq could be fixed to 9 since there are always 9 digits.

Comment: If I decide to do the allocate statement, how would I do the INTEGER, INTENT statement? I am changing it to INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: num, freq

Comment: You can use "dimension (:)" without the array being allocatable.  Even if the actual argument is an allocatable array (e.g., if you want to have various array lengths instead of always 100), the dummy argument in the subroutine doesn't need the allocatable attribute.  The subroutine argument needs "allocatable" only if you are using allocatable features within the subroutine.

Comment: can you give me an example of how the size can be fixed to 9. I have never used the size function before.

Comment: Three lines of example code: integer, dimension (:), intent (in) :: num;     integer, dimension (9), intent (in) :: freq;    do i=1, size (num).    So "size" tells you the dimension of the array without your having to explicitly pass it is as an argument.  If an array is fixed in length, then you might as well your have constant in the declaration.